# XCode: file.mobileprovisioning is disabled to be installed

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an iOS app which is ready to be loaded to the App Store using Application Loader. In https://developer.apple.com/ I have just created a new Development Provisioning Profile whose name is "Profile.name_project" and I have just downloaded it too. The problem is that damned file cannot be installed in my XCode. Following some questiones here in SO, I have learnt that I need to go Window->Devices->My Mac->Show provisioning profiles (on the gear icon). Then, when I try to add a new provisioning profile with the '+'button I navigate ti Download folder with Finder but the .mobileprovision file is gray and disabled, I can't add it. In fact, if I try to build my project I get

`Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “xxxxxxx” were found.`

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

After having done what Arik Segal suggested - which I had missed to do -, I selected the correct team in ProjectName -> team name.
I don't know why someone had set another team to which the provision file did not belong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading and installing it using Xcode:

1. Xcode->Preferences->Accounts
2. Click your Apple ID on the left pane
3. Double Click the relevant team name on the right pane
4. Click "Download" next to the name of the desired profile

Comment: Thank you. I have just tried it and downloaded the provision file as you said but I'm still getting "No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “xxxxxxx” were found." on Product -> Archive

Comment: Moreover if I perform Product->Archive-> fix issue to get the ipa this is the message: "You have a valid iOS Development certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can also reset your current certificate."

Comment: Did you click "Reset"? As far as I remember, doing this might help.